# supply a fallback value for TryFindResource in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, localization

The function TryFindResource will return null if the resource is not found.
Is there a way to supply some fallback value for any key that TryFindResource can't find?

We have a big project and it's not easy to replace TryFindResource with a wrapper. 
First approach was to implement our own ResourceDictionary and add it to MergedDictionaries but alas ResourceDictionary is a class not an interface and we can't override it's methods.

So I'm looking for a proper way to make TryFindResource not to return null on unknown resource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The least invasive method would be perhaps do a sweep over your codebase and use the extension method below. Anywhere you are invoking **FindResource** change that to **FindResourceEx**.

```
public static class FrameworkElementExtensions
{
  public static Object TryFindResourceEx(this FrameworkElement el, Object resourceKey)
  {
    var result = el.FindResource(resourceKey);

    if(result == null)
    {
      // fallback handling here
    }

    return result;
  }
}
```

Comment: This is for .cs files. What to do in .xaml like this?
<Image ToolTip="{StaticResource GoBack}"  />. This resource normally will be found in MergedDictionaries

Comment: Considering that the XAML parser throws an exception if a StaticResource is referenced by not defined, I would say it is invoking FindResource and not TryFindResource anyway. So you are out of luck.

Answer (score 0):

If I get it correct, then you can work with Extensions, which allow you to write fallback.

```
  public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
          var resource= Application.Current.TryFind("ApplicationResource");
        }
    }

    public static class ApplicationExtension
    {
        public static Object TryFind(this Application application,string resourceName)
        {
            return Application.Current.TryFindResource(resourceName) ?? "Your fall back resource";
        }
    }
```

Comment: That won't work because the compiler will always pick the instance method if the signature of an extension method matches an existing instance method.

Comment: Good thought. However, in my case method name is different. Do you still foresee issue ?

Comment: Not in case the name is different. Even though I'm pretty sure the OP was referring to a default value on a case by case basis.